# Непонятки с функциями конвертации VB6.0

Tags: visual-basic

> ? Text1.Text
>   1995.54
>
> ? cdbl(Text1.Text) Type mismatch
>
> ? cstr(Text1.Text)
>   1995.54
>
> ? cdbl(cstr(Text1.Text)) Type mismatch

Хоть убей, не пойму! Кто готов помочь!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задача только в том, чтобы правильно работала конвертация плавающего числа, независимо от установки десятичного разделителя в Windows ("." или ",") и независимо от того, какой разделитель введет юзер в диалоговом поле, то я вместо `CDbl(StrDbl)` применяю комбинацию: `Val(Replace(StrDbl,",","."))`

Функция `Val()` всегда ожидает точку в качестве десятичного разделителя, поэтому такая комбинация будет работать независимо от установок ОС и предпочтений пользователей...

Comment: cdbl(Replace(text1.text, ".", DecimalSeparator) помог, и как я сразу не догадался! :)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Переинсталируйте VB6.0 с другого инсталлятора. У меня работает любой вариант преобразования типов. Бывает иногда глюк с прочтением символа десятичного разделителя, если в текстбокс вводится этот символ, отличный от установленного в системе. Поэтому, чтобы наверняка, то :

```
Private DecimalSeparator As String * 1

Private Sub Form_Load()
DecimalSeparator = Format$(0, ".")
End Sub

Function Proceed() as Double
If DecimalSeparator <> "." Then
Proceed= cdbl(Replace(text1.text, ".", DecimalSeparator))
Else
Proceed=cdbl(Replace(text1.text, ",", DecimalSeparator))
End If
end function
```